# HighCharts lightweight widget/optimizations?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are currently using highcharts for displaying some data (with a lot of points).

Lets say there is a widget which displays highcharts (Which contains visitor count VS Time) in Highcharts.

We got 12 other highcharts like the that. Totally we are displaying about 15 highcharts in one page.

**Chrome crashes eventually because there is a lot of memory consumption by highcharts.**

**Is there anyway I can make it more lightweight or cut down few things to speed up highcharts?**

Please give your experience/insights on heavy usage of highcharts.

- R

Comment: Are this widgets constantly updating with data or are they static? Try turning off animations/shadows. If your charts that have a lot of points can be limited on number of points you can save some processing time.

Comment: @wergeld thank you for your response. We don't keep reloading the charts if that's what you are asking.

Comment: For the lots of points chart - how many points and how many charts have this?

Comment: Points vary from 10-1000 (even more?) but we have about 15 different highcharts. So 15x1000 = 15,000 points rendered in same page using backboneJS (our framework). The page gets laggy while loading all the charts inititally. It settles off once loaded but loading takes a while and browsers like firefox crashes because of this issue. @wergeld

Comment: Have you consider [boost](http://www.highcharts.com/articles/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost) module or [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo)

Comment: How big scale-wise are these charts? If they are widgets I would expect them to be small-ish. Why have 1000 points in a widget? Can you downsample your data such that the chart shows grouped values?

Comment: 15k points is nothing for HC. I have a project with over 64 charts on screen that update every one sec and each chart has 500-100 points. Your case has a memory load of about 120k, which is insignificant. There is something else, you initial load procedure is inneficient. And here's my tip: Do not try to compute values at that point, just have the data ready to be sent.